# having trouble calculating a summation

Tags: probability, summation

I was studying probability, and I found this summation, the problem is that i can't calculate it...
$$\sum_{x=r}^{\infty}\binom{x-1}{r-1}(qe^t)^{x-r}$$
The answer of this summation is: 
$$(1-qe^t)^{-r}$$

Comment: Write it in terms of the new index i= x- r.

Comment: let $k = qe^t$. change binomial and we get sum as $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{i}{r-1}k^{i} = (1-k)^{-r}$$

Comment: Thank you, I think the problem is solved with your help... thanks a lot @sku